# magento 2 catalog:images:resize. Stop and go?

Tags: image, caching, out-of-memory, magento2

Running magento 2.3.6
Launched php bin/magento catalog:images:resize command
Since I've got more than 600thousands of entries it will take a while.
Problem is: no matter how much memory do I give (-dmemory_limit=10G), it stops after few hours due to memory failure.
Is there a way to stop and resume?
I wonder why memory accumulates like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your memory issue you can use this module.

https://dolphinwebsolution.com/shop/catalog-image-resizer-for-magento.html

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: unfortunately this module can't manage missing images (contacted producer for support)

Comment: This module is working properly. can you please share screenshot.

Comment: I already use this extension in our 5-6 clients website and it's working perfect as per our expectation. If image is missing then how can they resize it. In front-end I think Magento will display placeholder image for that and I don't think we need to resize placeholder image for all missing images. If you have any other issue then please share screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: update: module is working as aspected, great support. I made a script on my own to add manually images from gallery via mysql since it take very long time to complete via command